# Staying in Bali for more than 60 days as a US citizen

Tags: visas, us-citizens, indonesia, bali

I'm a US citizen and I plan to enter Bali on a 60-day tourist visa. I will want to renew and get an additional 30 days. But I will be busy in the second half of that initial 60-day period. Is it possible to obtain a renewal well before the initial 60 days end? For example, after only 30 days of the 60-day visa period, can I apply and receive the 30 day renewal so that I'll have a total of 90 days to stay there?

Comment: A simple google search shows that you can get a 60 day visa and then renew it in 30 day increments. Was that not sufficient for some reason?

Answer (score 2):

Visa renewal in Indonesia is at best tricky. I might even say random and/or arbitrary.

As I remember (I once had this problem) you can only renew 15 days before expiration date.

The rule seems to be that you need a sponsor (just any local individual will do). Then, your sponsor can renew your passport in the immigration office where he officially lives (why? Go figure). I think that the presence of the passport owner is now compulsory **but was not before**.

This rule kind of bond you to the living place of your sponsor.

There used to be a business around passport renewal in Bali. You would give your passport to a local and he would get it stamped for you. I doubt it still works.

**In any case** I would advise that you make your plans assuming renewal will be rejected. Depending on the local zeitgeist, they might pick any excuse to reject your demand. For example, I've once been told that the sponsor letter may not be handwritten.

That said, immigration will not execute you if you overstay a few days or even a full month. They will fine you $25 per day, but it might be a solution for you. Just be sure not to overstay more than 30 days (I read 60 days, but I wouldn't push my luck in this situation)